# How is a dipole stable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dipole

So I was reading about dipoles, two charged particles of opposite charges a very small distance from each other. But if the particles have opposite charges, shouldn't they attract and crash into each other?

Comment: Evidently, realistic dipoles have a structure that keeps stably separated the charges thorugh another type of (repulsive) force between them.

Comment: consider a bar of non-conductive material where we used a particle accelerator to put extra + charges at one end and - charges at the other. The charges cannot combine because they are stuck in the material (due to all the other charges which cancel out but still have the effect of making our extra charges get stuck)

Comment: @user253751 a particle accelerator is a bit of overkill. One can accomplish this by rubbing a balloon on their shirt. (the phenomenon of electronegativity)

Comment: Obsviously an electron and a positron form a very unstable dipole. Between a heavy and a light particle of opposite charges,  the dipole is more stable. But a dipole moment generally appears because of a non symmetric charge distribution in the ground state.

Answer (score 5):

You are right. A dipole is not stable: the charges should attract eachother. But the situation is even worse. Because of [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem), there is no stable distribution of point charges possible - so it's not just a problem with dipoles, but all the charge distributions you study in your first few weeks of an electrostatics course. So why is any of electrodynamics possible?

I think a very broad answer to this question is that quantum mechanics allows electrons to behave in ways that classical electromagnetism wouldn't appreciate. If you want to know whether or not a molecule has a dipole moment, you solve the Schrodinger equation. And it is possible that the schrodinger equation says the molecule is in a lower energy state if there is more charge on one side than the other. In a very handwavy way - in sodium chloride, the chlorine atom has a lower energy state available for the extra electron than the sodium does, so it takes the extra electron. Hence molecules can be permanent dipoles.

But in an even more basic way, the concept of dipoles can be useful to understand how atoms respond to an electric field - which is also described by quantum mechanics. An atom will make a dipole moment proportional to the electric field. Another handwavy way to understand this is to think of the electron and the nucleus tied together by a spring.

And finally, using batteries, generators, and conductors separated by insulators, we can make whatever charge distributions we want, and sometimes dipoles are a useful way of understanding the electric field produced by those charge distributions far away. Batteries are again explained by quantum mechanics. As is the reason materials can be conductors - the electrons are in a lower energy state inside the conductor's "conduction band" of quantum states vs a small distance away outside the conductor. But generators are, as far as I can think, fully explainable by classical electrodynamics as long as you accept the existence of conductors and magnets.

Comment: I am extremely, extremely sorry for not replying on time, its my first time on this stack exchange, and I forgot I had ever asked a question. Also, since Im just a high schooler, I wont be able to comment on the validity your statement and mark it as correct. Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score -1):

> But if the particles have opposite charges, shouldn't they attract and crash into each other?

The hydrogen atom  consists of an electron and a proton. Approaching an electron to a proton will make a classical dipole, and as you state, on a straight path should be attracted and fall on the proton, neutralizing it. Thus the atom we know would not exist, nor the world we live in.

But the electron and the proton form the stable hydrogen atom, which cannot be modeled with classical electrodynamics. Quantum mechanics answers why the electron does not fall on the proton and neutralize it.

As with the planetary models [Bohr assumed](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html#c2) there would be orbits about the proton and axiomatically set a quantized angular momentum, so that the orbits would be stable and atoms could be described. Then the theory of [quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quacon.html) developed.

It is a large and mathematically complex theory.

Comment: H atom consists of a proton and an electron but is not a dipole because of the symmetry.

Comment: @M06-2x I will edit.

Comment: I still don't know the answer, but atleast I won't be banging my head on the wall anymore. Thanks :)